# How to detect parse/read failure of Boost.PropertyTree?

Tags: c++, boost

The documentation doesn't really say.

I get that I can hand it an ifstream, so I could check to make sure it's open, so that case is mostly dealt with.

But when doing boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini(ifstream_object,property_tree_object);

How do I detect if the file was in a bad format?  Is there any way for me to get diagnostic information, such as *where* the parse failed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just catch exceptions. Base PropertyTree exception class is [`boost::property_tree::ptree_error`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/ptree_error.html) which derives from [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error), and it has two descendants: [`ptree_bad_data`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/ptree_bad_data.html) and [`ptree_bad_path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/ptree_bad_path.html).

**Example:**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace property_tree;

    stringstream ss;
    ss << "good = value" << endl;
    ss << "bad something" << endl;
    try
    {
        ptree root;
        read_ini(ss, root);
    }
    catch(const ptree_error &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
<unspecified file>(2): '=' character not found in line
```